# Draw line using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a client that wants a landing page like this:

[image]

What he wants is for the lines that join the center image with the others to be animated (like if they were painted from the start point to the final point).

Is there any jQuery plugin to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html)?

Comment: Tell your client that we are not in 1993 anymore :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw using the HTML 5 canvas and straight JS:

With this HTML:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width=500></canvas>
```

And this Javascript:

```
x = 50;
y = 75
startx = 0;
starty = 75;

function drawIt() {

    var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue"; // Green path
    ctx.moveTo(startx, starty);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);

    ctx.stroke(); // Draw it    
    if (x > 350) {
        window.clearInterval(timerId);
    } else if (y <= 25 && x >= 250) {
        starty = 25;
        x += 5;
    } else if (y <= 75 && x >= 250) {
        x = startx = 250;
        y -= 5;
    } else {
        x += 5;
    }
}
timerId = window.setInterval(drawIt, 30);
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YjTsf/